# Why is my app totally hidden from Google play store app search results

Tags: android, google-play

I'm having trouble searching for my app on the Google play store app from my phone. My app, which can be found on [this link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=smart.Wil.daram.widgetlauncher) is totally hidden from search results.

I uploaded my app to Google play store on October 29, with the title: Widget Launcher. Until October 30, I was not able to see it in the search results, of the play store app, when I search for it by app title. But I was able to see it in search results when I search it by putting the title inside quotes.

On October 30, I changed its title to: Smart Widget Launcher. After that I couldn't see it in search results even by putting the updated title inside quotes. But I could still see it after searching with "Widget Launcher" (old app title inside quotes). I have made sure that the updated app name is stated multiple times inside the app description, and the Google play console stated that the update is live.

The weird thing is, as can be seen on the attached image, I could find it by searching with the updated title (Smart Widget Launcher) on the store, from inside the Firefox app. What am I missing?

[image: App search result on play store website, from inside Firefox app]

Comment: Wait a few days. My app didn't show in the search results until 4+ days after posting it.

Comment: Instead of down voting, please tell me the kind of clarification you needed?
Thanks @iTadreik

Comment: You might be getting down-voted because this is not a programming question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks @Knossos I was considering the Play Store as a tool commonly used by programmers, and that the problem I am facing may be a result of a programming mistake. Now that I think about it, it may appear as a proxy for customer support.

Comment: I would recommend Reddit as a good alternative for this kind of general question: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/ (there might be a relevant Stack Exchange, but I am not aware of one)

Answer (score 1):

After publish, there is time for dispatch. And after any update there is time for your changes to be effective. And visible on Google Play. The only thing you may have missed is **patience**. And that's what I may recommend you.

Comment: Google Play Store's team need to be more transparent with how these things work.

Comment: is it explainable why the app can be found after searching it on the play store website from a browser, but not on the play store app?

Answer (score 0):

For others facing similar issue, as [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element) guide explains, one of the reasons this may happen is setting a feature or permission asked as `android:required="true"` by default.

> To determine an application's feature compatibility with a given user's device, Google Play compares: features required by the application — an application declares features in `<uses-feature>` elements in its manifest, with features available on the device, in hardware or software — a device reports the features it supports as read-only system properties.
>
> By specifying the features that your application requires, you enable Google Play to present your application only to users whose devices meet the application's feature requirements, rather than presenting it to all users.

As is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element), The required attribute of the `<uses-feature>` needs to be set to false, if a specific feature is not required for your app to run. And Google Store will show your app to a device that doesn't support that feature.